# Local notification listener didn't perform action

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to add a listener to the local notification so when the user press on the notification a browser opens, this is my code :

```
  public class MyApplication {

private Form current;
private Resources theme;

Form hi;
Form web;

EncodedImage ei;
Image img;
String url = "https://d1fmx1rbmqrxrr.cloudfront.net/cnet/optim/i/edit/2019/04/eso1644bsmall__w770.jpg";

public void init(Object context) {
    // use two network threads instead of one
    updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

    // Pro only feature
    Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

    addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
        // prevent the event from propagating
        err.consume();
        if (err.getError() != null) {
            Log.e(err.getError());
        }
        Log.sendLogAsync();
        Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
    });
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        ei = EncodedImage.create("/loading.gif");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    img = URLImage.createToStorage(ei, url, url, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);

    LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
    n.setId("Welcome");
    n.setAlertBody("Welcome");
    n.setAlertTitle("Welcome");
    // n.setAlertSound("/notification_sound_bells.mp3"); //file name must begin with notification_sound
    n.setAlertImage(img.toString());

    n.setId("5");
    n.setBadgeNumber(0);
    Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
            n,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, // fire date/time
            LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE // Whether to repeat and what frequency
    );

    if (n.getBadgeNumber() > 0) {
        localNotificationReceived("5");
    }
    hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    web = new Form("web", BoxLayout.y());

    hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));

    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com/");
    web.add(browser);
    hi.show();
}

public void localNotificationReceived(String notificationId) {
    web.show();
}

public void stop() {
    current = getCurrentForm();
    if (current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog) current).dispose();
        current = getCurrentForm();
    }
}

public void destroy() {
}

}
```

but no action was executed on the moment of the press.
Another problem the image passed in the notification didn't appear.
I tried to see the official documentation but nothing useful found.

Comment: I don't see a call to localNotificationReceived, where is it defined. The code seems partial. Also img.toString() just returns debug information not the path to the image file.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I uploaded the whole code... Can you tell me how to test if the notification is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on APIs such as badging which aren't supported everywhere. You should remove that code. The reason notifications aren't invoked is that you didn't implement the `LocalNotificationCallback` interface in your main class. You just wrote the method without implementing the interface.